# Uncaught ReferenceError: j$ is not defined

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure why I get this error. Below is the entire test file. jQuery object doesn't appear to be initialized. Please help me understand what is the cause of the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jquery Test Program</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/skin/frontend/modello/default/slider/css/owl.carousel.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/skin/frontend/modello/default/slider/css/owl.theme.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/skin/frontend/modello/default/slider/css/owl.transitions.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/skin/frontend/modello/default/fonts/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/skin/frontend/modello/default/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/skin/frontend/modello/pmm/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/skin/frontend/modello/default/js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/skin/frontend/modello/default/slider/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
j$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Hi');
    j$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({itemsCustom:[[0,1],[380,2],[625,3],[1265,4],[1360,4],[1440,4],[1680,4]],autoPlay:false,stopOnHover:true,rewindNav:false,scrollPerPage:true});
    j$(".owl-prev").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>');
    j$(".owl-next").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Content</div>
<div id="addMultiSkusModal" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 493px;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
    <input type="text" id="addSkuModalText" style="width: 300px;" class="">
    <div id="addSkuModalResults" style="margin-top: 10px;overflow: auto;height: 457px;">
        <ul>
            <li style="margin: 2px 0;"><input name="selectedSku" type="checkbox" value="CZ000750000"><a>CZ000750000 - Cristal&amp;Bronze Bambou Large Square Bin, no Cover<br><span style="padding-left: 50px;color: #C0C0C0;">CZFS03-672-B3 - Cristal&amp;Bronze Bambou Large Square Bin, no Cover</span><br></a>
            </li>
            <li style="margin: 2px 0;"><input name="selectedSku" type="checkbox" value="CZ000770000"><a>CZ000770000 - Cristal&amp;Bronze Bambou Large Square Bin, no Cover<br><span style="padding-left: 50px;color: #C0C0C0;">CZFS03-672-E6 - Cristal&amp;Bronze Bambou Large Square Bin, no Cover</span><br></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't defined `j$` anywhere. The name of the jQuery object is `jQuery` and the default shorthand is `$`.

Comment: If you wanted to use `j$` for it, you could do `jQuery(function(j$) { /*...your code...*/});` Note that using `ready` on the `document` element has been deprecated for years. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3, https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @VLAZ, I did as you advised to find a new error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: tl;dr: OPs *underlying*  issue was that they had a 404 on jquery.js - check the console and network tab for errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert in jquery but wasn't their function always exported as `$` and not `j$`?

EDIT:
Thank you @freedomn-m for mentioning it. The root problem was, that the jquery source did not load. For anyone facing a similar problem, I suggest you use the official CDN instead of hosting your own version of jquery. You can find the URL for different versions and bundles here: https://code.jquery.com.

Comment: I did as you advised to find a new error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: I just checked your URL: `https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/skin/frontend/modello/default/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js` which gave me a 404. Could you make sure it loads for you and that it has the jquery source? Otherwise you can also add it via their cdn: `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: No, that doesn't. I think I should an universal link to jQuery resource.

Comment: Yup, I think the CDN will do you best ;)

Comment: Thanks, could you please share the link to it?

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help

Comment: As this answer was accepted, could you edit the answer to reflect the solution?   ie that they had a 404 and needed a new url to jquery.

Comment: @M1CH3L1US, I've a request for you. Could you please have a look at this post to see if you can suggest some solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910147/close-previously-opened-accordion-with-pure-javascript?noredirect=1#comment127070019_71910147